# Change the default title of the links from customer navigation in magento 1.8?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

I manage to remove the items that I don't want from the Customer Account Dashboard Links, following this [answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10334/how-to-remove-customer-account-dashboard-links),

```
   <ul>
        <?php $_links = $this->getLinks(); ?>
        <?php $_index = 1; ?>
        <?php $_count = count($_links); /* Add or Remove Account Left Navigation Links Here -*/
            //unset($_links['account']); /* Account Info */     
            //unset($_links['account_edit']); /* Account Info */            
            unset($_links['tags']); /* My Tags */
            unset($_links['invitations']); /* My Invitations */
            //unset($_links['reviews']);  /* Reviews */
            //unset($_links['wishlist']); /* Wishlist */
            //unset($_links['newsletter']); /* Newsletter */
            //unset($_links['orders']); /* My Orders */
            unset($_links['address_book']); /* Address */
            unset($_links['enterprise_customerbalance']); /* Store Credit */
            unset($_links['OAuth Customer Tokens']); /* My Applications */
            unset($_links['enterprise_reward']); /* Reward Points */
            unset($_links['giftregistry']); /* Gift Registry */
            unset($_links['downloadable_products']); /* My Downloadable Products */
            unset($_links['recurring_profiles']); /* Recurring Profiles */
            //unset($_links['billing_agreements']); /* Billing Agreements */
            unset($_links['enterprise_giftcardaccount']); /* Gift Card Link */
        ?>
        <?php foreach ($_links as $_link): ?>
            <?php $_last = ($_index++ >= $_count); ?>
            <?php if ($this->isActive($_link)): ?>
                <li class="current<?php echo ($_last ? ' last' : '') ?>"><strong><?php echo $_link->getLabel() ?></strong></li>
            <?php else: ?>
                <li<?php echo ($_last ? ' class="last"' : '') ?>><a href="<?php echo $_link->getUrl() ?>"><?php echo $_link->getLabel() ?></a></li>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
```

But, what about - if I want to change the order and the default name of them? For instance, I want to change them from,

```
Account Dashboard
Account Information
My Orders
Billing Agreements
My Product Reviews
My Wishlist
Newsletter Subscriptions
My Gift Cards
```

to,

```
My Dashboard
Account Information
Billing Agreements
My Orders
My Reviews
My Wishlist
My Gift Cards
Subscriptions
```

is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Its work 100% i am Sure.**

Step 1: Go To ( YourTemplate/customer/account/navigation.phtml )

Step 2: Replace This Line: `<?php $_count = count($_links); ?>`
With:

```
<?php $_count = count($_links); /* Add or Remove Account Left Navigation Links Here -*/
unset($_links['account']); /* Account Info */     
unset($_links['account_edit']); /* Account Info */            
unset($_links['tags']); /* My Tags */
unset($_links['invitations']); /* My Invitations */
unset($_links['reviews']);  /* Reviews */
unset($_links['wishlist']); /* Wishlist */
unset($_links['newsletter']); /* Newsletter */
unset($_links['orders']); /* My Orders */
unset($_links['address_book']); /* Address */
unset($_links['enterprise_customerbalance']); /* Store Credit */
unset($_links['OAuth Customer Tokens']); /* My Applications */
unset($_links['enterprise_reward']); /* Reward Points */
unset($_links['giftregistry']); /* Gift Registry */
unset($_links['downloadable_products']); /* My Downloadable Products */
unset($_links['recurring_profiles']); /* Recurring Profiles */
unset($_links['billing_agreements']); /* Billing Agreements */
unset($_links['enterprise_giftcardaccount']); /* Gift Card Link */
```

?>

Answer (score 1):

You can create a translation file,

create translate.csv in `app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/locale/languagecode_COUNTRYCODE`

and add in "Account Dashboard","My Dashboard"

and add similarly..

Answer (score 0):

[Managing navigation links in the account dashboard](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/managing-navigation-links/)

**Using this Add or remove dashbord link.**

OR

**Add Code into Local.xml**

```
<customer_account translate="label">
        <reference name="left">
            <!--Unset the whole block then add back later-->
            <action method="unsetChild"><name>customer_account_navigation</name></action>
            <block type="customer/account_navigation" name="customer_account_navigation" before="-" template="customer/account/navigation.phtml">
                <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>account</name><path>customer/account/</path><label>Account Dashboard</label></action>
                <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>account_edit</name><path>customer/account/edit/</path><label>Account Information</label></action>
                <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>address_book</name><path>customer/address/</path><label>Address Book</label></action>
                <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="sales"><name>orders</name><path>sales/order/history/</path><label>My Orders</label></action>
                <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="review"><name>reviews</name><path>review/customer</path><label>My Product Reviews</label></action>
                <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="wishlist" ifconfig="wishlist/general/active"><name>wishlist</name><path>wishlist/</path><label>My Favorite</label></action>
                <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="newsletter"><name>newsletter</name><path>newsletter/manage/</path><label>Newsletter Subscriptions</label></action>
            </block>


            <!--IF You want to remove -->
            <remove name="catalog.compare.sidebar"/>

        </reference>
</customer_account>
```

**Translate Magento inline text**

> ```
>  Go to System > Configuration > Developer > Translate Inline
> ```